# Listagg function is not working in sub query

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

Listagg function is not working when it used in subquery, though using listagg function in prod column is not concatenated all the products in single row

```
select
    a.id,
    a.num,
    (listagg(c.prod_name,',') within group(order by prod_name)
from product c
where c.prod_id = NVL(b.prod_id,b.prod_pos) As prod
from master a, base_product b
where
    b.id = a.id and
    b.type = 1 and
    a.id = 12345;
```

Comment: Your query makes not sense to me. Kindly share sample data and desired output to help us help you..

Comment: Base product table with value 1, has multiple products. those products name has been  retrieved by product ...those retrieved product should be in single row as comma seperated.

Comment: eg. if query extracts products of 1.bat 2.ball, 3. stumps, 4 .guard  it should be in single cell like bat, ball, stumps,guard

Comment: Kindly edit your question and add elaborated sample data along with desired output.

Comment: sample data
Id      num      prod  
-----------------------
101    1701A001   book
102    1701A001   data
103    1702B005   bat
104    1702B005   ball
105    1703C006   Stumps

My expected output should be

Id      num      prod  
-----------------------
101    1701A001   book, data
102    1701A001   book, data
103    1702B005   bat, ball
104    1702B005   bat, ball
105    1703C006   Stumps

Comment: expecting queries without inner /outer joins, if possible

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery in the select clause is lacking a `select` keyword, this is probably the immediate source of the error.  However, we can improve upon your query and instead join to a subquery which does the aggregation:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.num,
    coalesce(c.prod, 'NA') as prod
from master a
inner join base_product b
    on b.id = a.id
left join
(
    select listagg(prod_name, ',') within group(order by prod_name) as prod
    from product
) c
    on c.prod_id = NVL(b.prod_id, b.prod_pos) 
where
    b.type = 1 and
    a.id = 12345;
```

Besides refactorting the call to `listagg`, I also replaced your implicit join syntax with an explicit `inner join`.  This is the preferred way of writing the query, and this style because part of the ANSI SQL standard 25 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listagg(prod, ',') within group(ORDER BY prod)` with `group by` on column `num` in cte or derived table and join it to the main table to get `id` as below.

```
SELECT t2.id,
       t2.num,
       t1.prod
FROM
  (SELECT num,
          listagg(prod, ',') within group(
                                          ORDER BY prod) AS prod
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY num ) t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.num = t2.num
order by t2.id\\
```

*OR*

```
WITH t1 AS
  (SELECT num,
          listagg(prod, ',') within group(
                                          ORDER BY prod) AS prod
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY num)
SELECT t2.id,
       t2.num,
       t1.prod
FROM t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.num = t2.num
ORDER BY t2.id\\
```

*Given you sample data:*

```
ID  NUM         PROD
--------------------
101 1701A001    book
102 1701A001    data
103 1702B005    bat
104 1702B005    ball
105 1703C006    Stumps
```

**Result:**

```
ID  NUM         PROD
-------------------------
101 1701A001    book,data
102 1701A001    book,data
103 1702B005    ball,bat
104 1702B005    ball,bat
105 1703C006    Stumps
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/OPIV44911)**